# Dealing with different user permissions in different orgs when deploying profiles

Tags: apex, administration, profile, ant, migration-tool

I am trying to add profiles to our repository and use that to deploy to different orgs. The problem I'm dealing with is that each org has different user permissions and a user permission may work in one org but not the other. This gets even more complicated when there are other dependencies on user permissions. For example,
I want to deploy "ModifyAllData" for a profile. It works in org A; however, I see the error below when I try to deploy it to org B:

> Error: Permission ModifyAllData depends on permission(s): DeleteTopics, EditPublicDocuments, EditPublicFilters, EditPublicReports, EditPublicTemplates, ImportLeads, ManageCategories, ManageDashboards, ManageNetworks, SolutionImport, TransferAnyEntity, TransferAnyLead, UseTeamReassignWizards

Then when I add "EditPublicReports" to my repository, I cannot save it to Org A because it gives me the following error:

> unknown user permission "EditPublicReports".

I know I can manually fix these up before deploying but I'm hoping to find a universal and automatic solution to this instead of having to manually get involved. How can I do it?

Comment: This is a current pain point with profiles. My understanding is that the DX team is working on a Better Way, but there's no details yet.

Comment: When you say you added "EditPublicReports" do you mean in the scratch org or you added it to the file?

Comment: Oh! I'm using ANT and not DX. I meant in the deployment file